# Saving video from UIImagePickerController to Core Data on iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, core-data, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I need some guidance on how to save video data to core data so that I can retrieve it again later.

I have no problem retrieving the NSURL that is returned from UIImagePickerController but then I'm not sure how to go about saving the video data to Core Data. I can already save and retrieve regular images from Core Data but I'm not sure how to do the same for video data.

If I could be pointed in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea here would be to store the URL in your core data store, and let the video itself be stored in the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks bugeye. That's what I ended up doing. Basically I saved the filename as a string in Core Data then I save the actual file itself to the Documents dir.